# Match line that contains two strings from another file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep, text-processing

I have a file `source.txt` containing two columns of strings separated by a whitespace.

```
foo bar
foo baz
goo gaa
```

Also, there is another file `pattern.txt` which is a list of strings (1 per line) that should serve as pattern source. This could look like

```
foo
bar
goo
```

**The goal is to extract only lines, that contain two strings from the pattern file.**
Repetitions are fine (e.g. `foo foo` would be valid).

So the desired output here would be

```
foo bar
```

I managed to extract lines that contain at least one term from the pattern file with `grep`:

```bash
grep -wFf pattern.txt source.txt
```

The command above would return all lines from `source.txt` since at least one term from `pattern.txt` is present in each line. My approaches using piped `grep` commands (which are shown in related questions considering only two search terms) have not worked out.

`grep` is not mandatory. `awk`, `sed`, `perl` work as well. I have a solution in Python, but it is terribly slow (¬blazinglyfast).

Thank you!

### Response to Answers

My Python solution looks like this:

```py
import sys

f_pattern = sys.argv[1]
f_source = sys.argv[2]

with open(f_pattern, "r", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    pattern = set(fp.read().split("\n"))

with open(f_source, "r", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        w1, w2 = line.strip("\n").split(" ")
        if w1 in pattern and w2 in pattern:
            print(line, end="")  # \n still present in line string
```

Indeed, it's not that bad (time-wise) compared to some answers.
**(My) Python**

```
time python matcher.py pattern.txt source.txt 
>> 158,12s user 1,82s system 99% cpu 2:40,08 total
```

**awk by @Avinash Chandravansi**

```
time awk -F' ' 'FNR==NR {arr [$0];next} $2 in arr' pattern.txt source.txt
>> 106,72s user 5,69s system 99% cpu 1:52,88 total
```

Not quite sure yet, but I think that gives an incorrect result.

**awk by @KamilCuk**

```
time awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} {cnt=0; for (k in a) { cnt += $0~k; if (cnt >= 2){ print; break; }}}' pattern.txt source.txt
>> Unclear, more then 20 minutes. Ctrl+C
```

**awk by @Fravadona**

```
time awk 'FNR==NR {patterns[$0]; next}($1 in patterns) && ($2 in patterns)' pattern.txt source.txt
>> 95,45s user 2,46s system 99% cpu 1:38,03 total
```

^-- This seems to be the accepted answer (for me).

Comment: `I have a solution in Python, but it is terribly slow` I doubt it will be faster in something else, except startup time. Or the python _you_ wrote is slow.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Which of the two files is small enough to fit into RAM?

Comment: @Cyrus In my case, both files fit into ram. But `pattern.txt` is way smaller (260 kB vs. 8.7 GB)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `grep -F` so I guess that the "patterns" aren't regexps. Now, if you're looking for matching the full strings (and not a substring) then you can do:

```bash
awk '
    FNR == NR { patterns[$0]; next }
    ($1 in patterns) && ($2 in patterns)
' pattern.txt source.txt
```

Comment: `I guess that the "patterns" aren't regexps` exactly!

Answer (score 1):

With awk, store the patterns in array and then check if at least two match.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} {cnt=0; for (k in a) { cnt += $0~k; if (cnt >= 2){ print; break; }}}' pattern.txt source.txt 
foo bar
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;y/\n/|/;s#.*#/(&).*(&)/p;d#' patternFile | sed -Ef - file
```

Create a sed script from the patternFile and apply it to source file.

Using the same alternation regexp twice in the same match print the result, otherwise delete the line.